# iOS:navigationBar's title default font

Tags: ios, fonts, uinavigationbar

A simple question, how can I know the `navigationBar's` title default font?
and it default size is how big?

**> Edit**

By take the answer below:

```
UIFont *font = self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes[NSFontAttributeName];
NSLog(@"font_sys%@", font);
```

result is  `nil`

And in the lldb:

```
(lldb) po self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes
0x0000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "font-name", size: 30)!]
```

For default dimension, remove this instruction and print in debug the navigation bar font size (it's default since you don't have changed it)

Comment: How to print it in debug?

Comment: Stop using breakpoint in a place where you have visibility of navigation bar. Then, in log window write code you want after 'po' -> po UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes for example

Comment: It prints null for me.

Answer (score 0):

For get default font size and name Try to use:

```
UIFont *font = self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes[NSFontAttributeName];
```

For change font you can use this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:YOUR_FONT_NAME size:18], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:YOUR_COLOR}];
```

end you can add the same any other attributes

Hope this help

Comment: The question is how to get *default* font.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming using storyboards, Go to navigation controller and select navigation bar. Check the attributes inspector there you can see the font and change the size and font. Check the below attached image.

[image]

For Programmatically you can use,

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "SFUI-Bold", size: 17)!]
```

Comment: I see no font when i check the attributes inspector.

Comment: I guess @iSashok already gave the answer to get the default font.

Comment: If I didn't set title text attributes, then `UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes` always returns nil for me.